# Powershell - replace matching multiple regex criteria

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that is converting data in a PRN file to format codes imported into an application. An example of a line prior to conversion would be:

```
1234ABCD                                                                  PCODE 00
```

and after conversion

```
1234ABCD                                                                  
PCODE 00
```

In this file, all codes would begin with the letter P. The issue I'm running into with my current script is if the code has a P inside it. The result for code PMNOPQRS would be:

```
1234ABCD                                                                  
PMNO
PQRS 00
```

Here is the part of the script handling that part:

```
$con = Get-Content $outputFile

$con | % { $_ -creplace("P(?=[A-Z])", "`r`nP") } | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content $outputFile | Out-Null
```

There are other instances in the file such as names where a letter P would be followed by lower-case letters, but they are only followed by capital letters in codes. Codes are always preceded by blank space What would be the proper way to do a -creplace where P is preceded by blank space and followed by a capital letter? Would it be able to work with a code such as PPPPPPP?

EDIT:
Sorry I should have put all the data on a line. There are multiple instance of whitespace. A full line would be more like:

```
FirstnameLastname      1      1234566 1234ABCD                 PCODE 00
```

With a desired result of

```
FirstnameLastname      1      1234566 1234ABCD                 
PCODE 00
```

Comment: Why don't you split the whitespace?

Comment: Updated with an edit showing what would be on a full line in the file. In my first example I was just showing the part of the line I was having issues with.

Comment: You could try making this into a csv and then split it that way

Comment: I can give it a shot. There is another part of the script where I have it as a CSV running through Excel before it is saved as a PRN. The application it's imported to is really particular about column widths and whitespace. Would splitting it that way preserve the spacing?

Comment: Just got around to testing it and it worked great and preserved the whitespace I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-split` or `-csplit` on the preceding spaces.

```
# Assume $s contains your string
$s -csplit '\s+(?=P\p{Lu}+)'
```

`csplit` only matters for the `P` here. `\s` matches a space. `\p{Lu}` is an uppercase letter. `+` is one or more. `(?=)` is a positive lookahead from the current position.

Comment: Worked like a charm. First import went through with no errors. Thank you!